# Retrieve array of dictionaries, from a dictionary in swift

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, ios8

I have a json response, which among other things contains an array of dictionaries. I want to be able to copy that array in to an existing array.

The way I did it in objective-C was like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *venuesArray = responseDictionary[@"response"][@"venues"];

        completion(venuesArray, error);
    });
```

In swift it has to be something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                var error: NSError?
                let responseDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as Dictionary
                let venuesArray : AnyObject[] = (responseDictionary as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("response.venues")
                completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error);
            });
```

But this gives me the following error:

`'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'AnyObject[]`'

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you declaration of `AnyObject[]`:
The error('***AnyObject' is not convertible to 'AnyObject[]'***) clearly states that, there is no array initialisation.

if The initialiser should be the Array values then use for `AnyObject[]`, check the responses value first.

Replace:

```
let venuesArray : AnyObject[] = (responseDictionary as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("response.venues")
```

To

```
let venuesArray : AnyObject = (responseDictionary as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("response.venues")
```

Comment: I got rid of the first error. Now the app runs, but crashes immediately. Here is a picture: http://imgur.com/3RL60yf. Thanks for helping out